# Отправить get запрос и получить ответ

Tags: java, android

Как отправить Get запрос на сервер (К примеру: `http://test.com/names.php?name=1`) и получить ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `HttpURLConnection`

Например

```
public void getAnswer() {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf8"));
            String answer = "";
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                answer += line;
            }

            reader.close();

            Log.d("tag", answer);
        }

        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вызывать метод нужно не в главном потоке. Пример асинхронного вызова

```
private class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            getAnswer();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

В `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new GetTask().execute();
    }
```

И обязательно добавить в манифест разрешение

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой метод я использую для вытягивания xml с новостями:

```
public String getXMLString() {
        String xml2String = null;
       try{
            URL rssURL = new URL("http://адрес_скрыт/rss.xml");
            URLConnection yc = rssURL.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = bufReader.readLine(); 

            while( line != null){ 
                sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
                line = bufReader.readLine(); 
            }
            bufReader.close();

            xml2String = sb.toString(); 

        }catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        } 
       return xml2String;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Используя `HttpUrlConnection`.

Вот почитайте.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html